# align label with input text and keep input with a large width

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4

There is a lot of questions like mine here, but I never found a solution.

I would like to have label and the input field align in the same line, but the input field must fit the width of the page.

I've tested something here which seems to do the job : https://jsfiddle.net/5n1re8x2/1/

But when I go back to me php page, it's not working as expected.

On this capture below you see that the input text for "code" is too small

Second and third lines I've not apply the `display: inline-block;` and `form-inline` but the width of the input field is my expected result.

[image]

So i'm quite stuck here

Here my code

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 10%;
        }

        input[type=text] {
            width: 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="card-header">

        <h3><i class="fas fa-edit mr-2"></i>Edit errors <span class="float-right">
                            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
                    </h3>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form action="access/editerrors.inc.php" method="POST" class="p-4">
                    <div class="form-group form-inline">
                        <label style="text-align: left;" for="code">Code:</label>

                        <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">

                    </div>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="titre">Titre:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="titre" name="titre" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message">Message:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use horizonal-forms for that, you have example here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Also here is working example of yours code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Boostrap 4 form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <main role="main" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card w-100">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3><i class="fas fa-edit mr-2"></i>Edit errors <span class="float-right"><a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a></span></h3>
                </div>
                <form action="access/editerrors.inc.php" method="POST" class="p-4">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="code" class="col-form-label col-sm-1">Code:</label>
                        <div class="col w-100">
                            <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="titre" class="col-form-label col-sm-1">Titre:</label>
                        <div class="col w-100">
                            <input type="text" id="titre" name="titre" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="message" class="col-form-label col-sm-1">Message:</label>
                        <div class="col w-100">
                            <input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]